# Drag&Drop on demand: How can I enable, start and continue dragging all within a single mousedown event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

So I have over 9000 elements each of which should be able to be dragged around. It doesn't seem feasible to turn each of them into draggable by applying the jQueryUI plugin directly. I was thinking about making an element draggable in response to a mouse down event by listening to the mouse down event of the document and checking if the target of the event is one of the elements. Once the mouse down on an element happened I turn it into a draggable **and** at the same time make it being captured and dragged already so that the dragging continues as if that mouse down initiated the dragging. Once dragging is finished (either by dropping or cancelling) the draggable pluging is destroyed and the element gets back to unbound state. This way only one element at a time can be dragged making this solution lightweight and scalable.

How can I do this?

Comment: @undefined, that's exactly the point, I can't make draggable all of them, please read the question carefuly

Comment: I have read the question _carefully_, the existence of 9000 elements in the same page is itself a problem.

Comment: 9000 is figurative number, the exact number is not important, what's important is that I can't apply draggable to each element due to their big number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [`draggable("destroy")`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy):

```
function downHandler(event)
{
    var target = $(event.target);
    target.off("mousedown", downHandler); // prevents infinite recursion
    target.on("mouseup", upHandler);
    target.draggable();
    target.trigger(event);
}

function upHandler(event)
{
    var target = $(event.target);
    target.draggable("destroy");
    target.off("mouseup", upHandler);
    target.on("mousedown", downHandler);
}

$(".draggable-on-mousedown").on("mousedown", downHandler);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jPjKN/

Comment: That's neat! I didn't know that an event can be sink by the trigger method like this.